# Cannot safely remove device

Tags: windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive, usb-storage

Am unable to safely remove my hard disk even after ensuring that all the running programs are closed. Am fearing it may damage my disk. How best can I go about it?

Comment: Log out of Windows (sign out) and then remove the device. That is very safe.

Comment: I would not only log out but shut the computer down.

Comment: If you are trying to figure out why you can't safely disconnect, use the system internals process explorer and search for open handles on the device.  You should see which process is attempting the keep the device open.  Chances are, the process is crapware.

Comment: Oh, and @John suggestion is exactly what you do if you can't figure out why the drive is being kept open.  Lets hope that we can figure it out though.

Comment: I will be trying that except that I have will be inconvenienced a bit.